# updating list with useState more than once results in wrong output

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I am struggling with handling a list with useState in React. I have to add an item to the list twice in a row, and only the second item is added. The code:

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ItemForm from "./itemForm";

function App() {
  const [itemList, setItemList] = useState([]);

  function addItem(item) {
    setItemList([...itemList, item]);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ItemForm onAddItem={ addItem } />
      { itemList && 
          itemList.map((item, i) => <ul key={ i + itemList } >{ item }</ul>) }
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**ItemForm.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function ItemForm({ onAddItem }) {
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

    function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var item = e.target.item.value;
        // Here, I have to call onAddItem twice.
        onAddItem(item);
        onAddItem(item + " second time");
        
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit } >
                <input value={ inputValue }  
                onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value) }  name="item"></input>
                <button type="submit">Add</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ItemForm;
```

This is the **actual behavior** of the app:

[image: actual behavior]

And this is the **expected behavior**:

[image: expected behavior]

why this happens and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**State updates are asynchronous**

For your two calls,the itemsList array is exactly the same. :

Suppose you have an array : `[1,2,3]`. What your code essentially does is make it `[1,2,3,4]` for the first time, and `[1,2,3,5]` for the second time.

```
setItemList([...itemList, item]) //[1,2,3,4]
setItemList([...itemList, item]) //[1,2,3,5]
```

Your array in the second update is still using the original value.

One way to do this you can use this pattern which uses the previous state. This is a reliable way to use the previous state.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ItemForm from "./itemForm";

function App() {
  const [itemList, setItemList] = useState([]);

  function addItem(item) {
    setItemList(itemList => ([...itemList, item]));
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ItemForm onAddItem={ addItem } />
      { itemList && 
          itemList.map((item, i) => <ul key={ i + itemList } >{ item }</ul>) }
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function ItemForm({ onAddItem }) {
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

    function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var item = e.target.item.value;
        // Here, I have to call onAddItem twice.
        onAddItem(item);
        onAddItem(item + " second time");
        
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit } >
                <input value={ inputValue }  
                onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value) }  name="item"></input>
                <button type="submit">Add</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ItemForm;
```

Comment: Problem is not the asynchronous nature of the state update; issue is that state is constant within a particular render of a component. That is why, calling `onAddItem` twice adds to the _same_ array. Function `addItem` has a closure over the value of `itemList` and calling that _same_ instance of a function will add the new item to the value of `itemList` that it closed over.

Answer (score 1):

Function passed to `ItemForm` component as a prop, i.e. `onAddItem`, has a closure over the value of `itemList` that was in-effect when that function was created.

As a result, calling that function twice with a different value for `item` creates a new array with the *same* value of `itemList` that the `addItem` function closed over.

**Example:**

If the `addItem` function pass to the `ItemForm` component has a closure over the initial value of `itemList`, i.e. an empty array; then the following state setter function call:

```
setItemList([...itemList, item]);
```

spreads the empty array and then adds the new `item` as shown below.

```
setItemList([...[], item]);
```

Calling `addItem` function twice is same as:

```
setItemList([...[], item]);
setItemList([...[], item]);
```

Also note that the state is constant within a particular render of a component. Component can't see the updated state until it is re-rendered.

#### Solution

You can pass a function to `setItemList` to update the state based on the previous value of `itemList`:

```
function addItem(item) {
   setItemList(currentState => [...currentState, item]);
}
```

Alternate option is to pass an array to the `onAddItem` function:

```
onAddItem([item1, item2]);
```

and change the `addItem` function as:

```
function addItem(itemsArr) {
   setItemList([...itemList, ...itemsArr]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

React doesn't update the state immediately after you call `setState`, it takes all of `setState` calls, and runs them before re-render.

So in your case, the second `onAddItem` is overriding the first one.

To solve such issues, you need to change some logic in your code for example:

```
  function addItem(...newItems) {
    setItemList(previousItemList => ([...previousItemList, ...newItems]));
  }
```

Now you can pass multiple items to add item and call it only once.

```
 onAddItem(item, item + " second time");
```